# Fatal error: $this->db->where()->join()->num_rows()

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, where-clause, mysql-num-rows

I want to make codeigniter pagination with where db query.

**My model:** *(update)*

```
public function get_all_produk_row($url = ''){
  data = array();
  $this->db->where(array('kategori.url'=>$url,'produk.status_produk'=>'1'));
  $this->db->order_by('kategori_id');
  $this->db->join('kategori','kategori.id_kategori=produk.kategori_id');
  $this->db->num_rows();
  return $data;
}
```

But I got Fatal error: `Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::num_rows()`.

How can I solve it?

---

My database

Kategori:

```
id_kategori
kode_kategori
url
```

Produk:

```
id_produk
kategori_id
kode_produk
status_produk
```

Comment: produce: `SELECT * FROM (produk) JOIN kategori ON kategori.id_kategori=produk.kategori_id WHERE kategori.url = '$url' AND produk.status_produk = '1' ORDER BY kategori_id`.

Where I must put `num_rows()` code?

Comment: U need to use numrows after execute query function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get no of rows after calling `get()` function as:

```
public function get_all_produk_row($url = '')
{ 
    $data = array(); 
    $this->db->where(array('kategori.url'=>$url,'produk.status_produk'=>'1')); 
    $this->db->join('kategori','kategori.id_kategori=produk.kategori_id'); 
    $this->db->order_by('kategori_id'); 
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
         $data = $query->result_array();
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing table name here

```
public function get_all_produk_row($url = '')
{     
  $data = $this->db->get_where("kategori",array('kategori.url'=>$url,'produk.status_produk'=>'1'))->num_rows(); 
 //or one method can be if you can write query 
 //$data = $this->db->query("select count(*) as total tbl_name")->row()->total; 
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: The table name is: **kategori** and **produk**. I want count how much row I get from this **where** query

Comment: How these 2 table's are connected to each other  ?

Comment: i mean is there any common column name  ?

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be as below:-

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->where($your_conditions);
$num_results = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

OR

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('whatever');
$query = $this->db->get('table');
$num = $query->num_rows();
```

Comment: I got Error Number: 1064. _SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` WHERE `kategori`.`url` = 'baterai' AND `produk`.`status_produk` = '1'_

Comment: Your query should be :- SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows FROM TableName WHERE kategori.url = 'baterai' AND produk.status_produk = '1'   .  You have missed TableName

Comment: I using array where codeigniter. And I got that produce

Comment: Check my second portion of answer.

Comment: Thanks dude, but what I should fill 'table' while I have 2 tables here?

Comment: Post your both tables in your question.